# run two threads simultaneously with different sleep times

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a situation to run thread1 every minute and thread2 every hour. How can i do this.

currently I have a working code to run thread1 after every minute.

main method

```
    static void main(string args[]){
      orderListner thread1 = new orderListner();
      thread1.start();
    }
```

thread1

```
    public static void orderListner extends thread{
      public void run(){
        while(true){
          process();
          thread.sleep(60000);
        }
      }
    }
```

Now I need to start new thread for results which runs after every hour. how I can implement this simultaneously(thread1 will continously run thread2 should start every hour)

Comment: Why not use two timers instead?

Comment: Use timertask . Take a look here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: If you can do t for every minute, you can do it for every hour. Just multiply the sleep time by 60. What am I missing? Please explain what you want to do more explicitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to use to the thread class is to make an object that implements Runnable instead of extending thread. If you don't want to make another file, simply make an anonymous class. (It's a good habit to avoid using inheritance whenever possible.)

That being said, just make a new thread that runs on the hour and start it. I will use your method of threads instead.

```
    static void main(string args[]){
          orderListner thread1 = new orderListner();
          orderListner2 thread2 = new orderListner2();
          thread1.start;
          thread2.start;
        }
```

thread 1 is the same and thread 2 is

```
public static void orderListner2 extends thread{
      void run(){
        while(true){
          process();
          thread.sleep(3600000);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. in main method we are defining thread1.start; this means the cursor wont return to this class untill thread1 terminates, to start thread2.

Comment: if you take notice about the method names defined in the thread class, and the methods called to start the thread classes, they are not the same. the thread code is defined in a method named `run`, while the thread is actually started by calling a method named `start`. inside `start` all kinds of dark magic is invoked, which means that the code inside your `run` method is run __separately__ from the other code, and the method `start` returns back to main almost instantly. after that, the second thread is started in the same wizardly manner ;)

Comment: Sleeping the thread is not a good way to schedule your executions. A better way is to use a timer or scheduler - look at the @mre's answer.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to centralize these tasks.

---

```
public final class ScheduledExecutorServiceDemo {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService exec = 
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Schedule first task
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do stuff
            }}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Schedule second task
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do stuff
            }}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example tells you wat needs to be done. http://gallemore.blogspot.com/2007/05/java-threading-scheduledexecutorservice.html  Happy coding!

Comment: @user877333, See also: [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

well done so far! :)

you can just do the same again. what i mean by this is that you create a new class that represents your second thread (we can call this class `SecondListener`). it should look like `OrderListener`, but the sleep time should be changed to make it 1 hour.

then you just modify your main method so that it creates one object of the SecondListener class, and starts the thread, like you do with the OrderListener.

if it's important that the SecondListener doesn't run it's first run until after one hour, you can execute sleep before process in SecondListener.

and finally a small suggestion about sleep times: express them as equations for readability's sake. so instead of 60000, type 1000 * 60. and instead of 3600000 type 1000 * 60 * 60 :)

Comment: what if the first process() method takes 50 seconds to execute? Will the program above behave as expected?

Comment: @cheekoo Yes it will still work, when you start a new thread you get a new process. You have 2 processes running the second one does not care whether or not the first one is done.

Comment: no no.. i guess I did not explain properly. If he wants thread1 to execute at every start of minute and process method takes 50 seconds, will the next execution (of same thread) start at start of next minute?

Comment: thread != process. You don't have a new process when staring a thread. A process has its own address space. A thread does not. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

Comment: @cheekoo of course it won't, but then op will find out, and ask a new question about that. this way op will learn the trade bit by bit. as it should be learned ^^

Comment: @jb are you referring to my expression "you can execute sleep before process in SecondListener"?

Comment: he is referring to "when you start a new thread you get a new process. " which i missed